# How to make a Spring Shell command fail?

Tags: java, spring, spring-shell

Imagine I have following Spring Shell commands class:

```
import org.springframework.shell.core.CommandMarker;

@Component
public class MyShellCommands implements CommandMarker {

    @CliCommand(value = COMMAND_RUN, help = "")
    public String run() {
        [...]
        // Something can go wrong here
        [...]
    }
}
```

If some error occurs in the method, I want the command to fail.

How can I make the `run` command fail, i. e. make sure that in case of error in the command, following assertion fails:

```
JLineShellComponent shell = ...;
final CommandResult result = shell.executeCommand("run");
assertThat(result.isSuccess()).isTrue(); // I want result.isSuccess() to be false, if run fails
```

?

Comment: Throw a runtime exception?

Comment: @beerbajay I tried it, but the unit test doesn't fail in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Throwing a runtime exception **does** work, you'll even be able to retrieve it via `CommandResult.getException()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code from [spring-shell](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-shell/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/shell/core/AbstractShell.java) where the CommandResult is set to true or false.

Just look for occurances of `return new CommandResult(false...` and try to see if you can cause any of the scenarios that lead to the that to occur.

For example I notice that if the `parseResult == null` then a false status is set.

```
public CommandResult executeCommand(String line) {
    // Another command was attempted
    setShellStatus(ShellStatus.Status.PARSING);

    final ExecutionStrategy executionStrategy = getExecutionStrategy();
    boolean flashedMessage = false;
    while (executionStrategy == null || !executionStrategy.isReadyForCommands()) {
        // Wait
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}
        if (!flashedMessage) {
            flash(Level.INFO, "Please wait - still loading", MY_SLOT);
            flashedMessage = true;
        }
    }
    if (flashedMessage) {
        flash(Level.INFO, "", MY_SLOT);
    }

    ParseResult parseResult = null;
    try {
        // We support simple block comments; ie a single pair per line
        if (!inBlockComment && line.contains("/*") && line.contains("*/")) {
            blockCommentBegin();
            String lhs = line.substring(0, line.lastIndexOf("/*"));
            if (line.contains("*/")) {
                line = lhs + line.substring(line.lastIndexOf("*/") + 2);
                blockCommentFinish();
            } else {
                line = lhs;
            }
        }
        if (inBlockComment) {
            if (!line.contains("*/")) {
                return new CommandResult(true);
            }
            blockCommentFinish();
            line = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf("*/") + 2);
        }
        // We also support inline comments (but only at start of line, otherwise valid
        // command options like http://www.helloworld.com will fail as per ROO-517)
        if (!inBlockComment && (line.trim().startsWith("//") || line.trim().startsWith("#"))) { // # support in ROO-1116
            line = "";
        }
        // Convert any TAB characters to whitespace (ROO-527)
        line = line.replace('\t', ' ');
        if ("".equals(line.trim())) {
            setShellStatus(Status.EXECUTION_SUCCESS);
            return new CommandResult(true);
        }
        parseResult = getParser().parse(line);
        if (parseResult == null) {
            return new CommandResult(false);
        }

        setShellStatus(Status.EXECUTING);
        Object result = executionStrategy.execute(parseResult);
        setShellStatus(Status.EXECUTION_RESULT_PROCESSING);
        if (result != null) {
            if (result instanceof ExitShellRequest) {
                exitShellRequest = (ExitShellRequest) result;
                // Give ProcessManager a chance to close down its threads before the overall OSGi framework is terminated (ROO-1938)
                executionStrategy.terminate();
            } else {
                handleExecutionResult(result);
            }
        }

        logCommandIfRequired(line, true);
        setShellStatus(Status.EXECUTION_SUCCESS, line, parseResult);
        return new CommandResult(true, result, null);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        setShellStatus(Status.EXECUTION_FAILED, line, parseResult);
        // We rely on execution strategy to log it
        try {
            logCommandIfRequired(line, false);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {}
        return new CommandResult(false, null, e);
    } finally {
        setShellStatus(Status.USER_INPUT);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what do I need to do in a command method in the `MyShellCommands .run` in order for that command to fail?